# How to disable some checkboxes of checkboxlist based on database value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a checkboxlist which has 26 values getting filled from database.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:CheckBoxList>

public QueSet()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.DatabaseConnectionString);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_SelectQueSet",conn); 
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;          
            SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sa.Fill(ds);
            if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {this.Data = ds.Tables[0];}
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {conn.Close();}

    }

QueSet q = new QueSet();
chkList1.DataSource = q.Data;
chkList1.DataBind();
```

Based on above code, the checkboxlist gets data from database. One of the values from the database is "Nothing" with ID 51.

I want to disable all the other checkboxes if user selects "Nothing" value.

```
protected void chkList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //what should I do here?
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to take a peek at this article. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easly achived by Client Script, Server SelectedIndexChanged is not required. do the steps as follows

1. Remove AutoPostback = "true" and  OnSelectedIndexChanged="..." from
   your CheckboxList control  and Add the property CssClass ="CHKList"
2. Attach jQuery.js  , say jQuery-1.7 or latest version

Add the following code in ASPX Page. This will disable all checkboxes when anyone of check box is clicked and Enable back if unchecked

```html
   
<script>


   $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".CHKList input:checkbox").click(function () {

                if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                    $(".CHKList input:checkbox").prop("disabled", true);//older version of jQuery prop will not work , use attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $(this).prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else {
                    $(".CHKList input:checkbox").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set data source to checkboxlist as your are doing

Then try this (Not tested, sorry for that)

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkList.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Chkboxlist.Items[i].Value == "SomeValue")
    {
        Chkboxlist.Items[i].Enabled = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to disable rest of the checkboxes if "Nothing" is selected. Your code with disable "Nothing" checkbox, right?